# How to use Collective and Blade to get the time difference in Laravel

Tags: laravel, datetime, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

I wish to calculate $time_used with using Collective and Blade in Laravel.

All date format of time_start, time_stop and time_used is timestamp in DB.

I tried to calculate with using Carbon, but I couldn't got time_used.

Also "time_start" from "created_at" and "time_stop" from "deleted_at" in DB.

Could you tell me how to get the time difference.
Thanks.

in \show_fields.blade.php

```
    <!-- Time Start Field -->
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('time_start', 'Time Started:') !!}
        <p>{!! $job->created_at !!}</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Time Stop Field -->
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('time_stop', 'Time Stopped:') !!}
          <p>{!! $job->deleted_at !!}</p>            
    </div>

    <!-- Time Used Field -->
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('time_used', 'Time Used:') !!}
        <p>{!! $job->time_used !!}</p>
    </div>
```

Result was as below...

```
Job Started:
2017-09-17 17:51:39

Job Stopped:
2017-09-17 17:51:49

Time Used:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the difference in seconds between the two `timestamps` and then format it to `H:i:s`

`gmdate("H:i:s",Carbon::parse($job->deleted_at)->diffInSeconds(Carbon::parse($job->created_at)));`

Or

`Carbon::parse($job->deleted_at)->diff(Carbon::parse($job->created_at))->format('%H:%I:%S');`

Which should return something like `00:00:10` in the format `Hours:Minutes:Seconds`

Comment: Thank you @Norris , the second one's result was 
[ErrorException]
Call to a member function diff() on string. have you other way?

Comment: <td>{!! gmdate("H:i:s",$job->deleted_at->diffInSeconds($job->created_at))!!}<td> is it right?

Comment: Error was 
Call to a member function diffInSeconds() on string

Comment: this means the dates are strings and not carbon instances. I edited my answer and parsed the dates to carbon instances

Comment: Thank you so much @Norris... the second one was working...:) as
<td>{!! \Carbon\Carbon::parse($job->deleted_at)->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($job->created_at))->format('%H:%I:%S')!!}<td>

Comment: And.... @Norris, How could I put the $time_used value to server when I deleted colum in table? thanks

Comment: Do you have a time_used field in your database or you want to perform an action based on the value on the server

Comment: Yes. I have time_used field. also time_stop, time_start, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at, too. :)

Comment: `public function destroy($id)
    {
        $job = $this->jobRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        if (empty($job)) {
            Flash::error('Job not found');

            return redirect(route('jobs.index'));
        }
        $job->time_used = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($job->deleted_at)->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($job->created_at))->format('%H:%I:%S');
        $this->jobRepository->delete($id);

        Flash::success('Job stop successfully.');

        return redirect(route('jobs.index'));
    } `

Is it correct? @Norris

Comment: Are you using laravel 5.5?

Comment: Do $Job->save(); after setting the time used

Comment: You might also want to clean your code by moving this into a method in your repository

Comment: The result was "0000-00-00 00:00:00"....
Could you tell me more detailed code? 
I made `$job->time_used = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($job->deleted_at)->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($job->created_at))->format('%H:%I:%S');
        $job->save();
        $this->jobRepository->delete($id);

        Flash::success('Job stop successfully.');

        return redirect(route('jobs.index'));
    }`
Thanks.@Norris

Comment: @Magnetic change your migration column type of the `$time_used` from `dateTime` to `time` and do  `$job->time_used = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($job->deleted_at)->diff(\Carbon\Carbon‌​::parse($job->create‌​d_at))->format('%H:%‌​I:%S'); $job->save();`

Comment: thank you for your friendly answer :) the result was 
`Class 'Carbon‌​‌​\Carbon‌​‌​' not found` so I did defined `use Carbon\Carbon;`
but it was same result...what is problem to use Carbon?

Comment: But it was working before? Hope you didn't add the code to the migration rather